# Is WSO2 IS 5.3.0 Compatible with Java 11?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm currently using WSO2 IS 5.3.0 and would like to know whether it is compatible with Java 11 in order to configure SAML SSO. If it is compatible are there any pre-requisites in setting up SAML SSO?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this documentation: [WSO2 IS 5.3.0 Installation Prerequisites](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Installation+Prerequisites), you can see *All WSO2 Carbon-based products are Java applications that can be run on any platform that is **Oracle JDK 7/8 or OpenJDK 8 compliant***. Of course there is no information about Java 11 (it was under developing), but in documentation for newer version, for example: IS 5.4.0 you will se: *Any JDK except JDK 8 is **not** supported.*

The IS 5.3.0 was relesed in 2017year, and Java 11 released in 2018, Therefore, WSO2 IS 5.3.0 could not be compiled in Java 11, and does not provide backward compatibility. I think you should consider update your IS to at least to 5.9.0 (for Java 11), or newer, if only for critical security updates.